# Can't launch the AVD on the Android Studio 2.3

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I'm using Android Studio 2.3.1 on my Ubuntu17 system and I'm newbie in Android developement.
So when I wanted to test my first code on the AVD I got this screen:
[image]

So when I choose the Nexus Virtual Device nothing happens and this is what i got:
[image]

Nothing happens and I see always the message:

> Waiting for target device to come online.

And aftre a while I got this message:

> Error while waiting for device: Timed out after 300seconds waiting for emulator to come online.

Of course I enabled ADB Integration.

Please any help for this problem

Comment: I had this same problem with a new install on Windows yesterday. The only difference is that I tried to start the emulator from the AVID Manager.

Comment: I did it but the issue remains

Comment: I don't follow. You did what?

Comment: I started the emulator from the AVD manager but the problem is not solved

Comment: I was just confirming that this also seems to be a problem on Windows

Answer (score 3):

I highly suggest that don't use AS AVD instead install Genymotion its free in your `File > Settings > Plugins` then search for Genymotion and install. But sometimes Virtual Device is not accurate in your phones DPI. Then you should build or test your application using a real device :)

Comment: With the advent of virtualization, Genymotion is not as necessary as it once was. I dare say it is even becoming obsolete. The emulator that comes with the SDK is very responsive now.

Comment: but if you want to achieve better results just run it in real device :)

Comment: Yes, all apps should be tested on a physical device before release. This is not always possible during development.

Comment: I don't think Genymotion is free, anyway I installed the plugin but how to use it?

Comment: its free you can see genymotion logo in your toolbar named Genymotion Device Manager its like a Device with a infinity logo :) its hard to teach you with text :) if you can't run it. Just visit youtube. anyway cheers bruh

Comment: Thank you very much, I installed Genymotion and it's working fine, but the I still want to use the AVD and resolve this issue.

Comment: oh thank you for up voting this answer. i think AS AVD is a bit slower, that's why other devs using genymotion rather than AS AVD. But i suggest that don't rely on Virtual Device output :) better to use a real device so you can achieve good design :)

Answer (score 0):

The correct type of emulator needs to be downloaded based on the processor for your host machine.
Install the correct one and try again. For example, Intel or AMD

*I recall having a similar issue in the past while using Android Studio